# How can one speed up this correlation calculation in R without multicore?

Tags: r, correlation, efficiency

I have a colleague who calculates correlations in which one set of scores for a subject (e.g. 100 scores) is correlated with another set of scores for that same subject. The resulting correlation reflects the degree to which those sets of scores are associated for that subject.  He needs to do this for N subjects. Consider the following dataset:

```
ncol <- 100
nrow <- 100
x <- matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow,ncol)
y <- matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow,ncol)
```

The correct output vector of correlations would be:

```
diag(cor(t(x),t(y)))
```

Is there a faster way to do this without using a multicore package in R?

Comment: I assume that 'without multicore' means without parallelism at all?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: the question in addition to the answers make me think this should be stackexchange... there should be a discussion on meta about questions with "how to speed up" ....

Comment: The discussion Robin called for is now on meta: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-to-speed-up-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While making a call to `diag` you throw out a lot of information, so you can save time by simply not calculating it. You code is equivalent to:

```
sapply(1:100,function(i) cor(x[i,],y[i,]))
```

**Extended to reflect comments:** This code will be slower for small matrices since it does not use the full "vectorization power" of `cor`. So, if you'd like to make fast calculations on small matrices, write it as a C chunk. If one would like to parallelize it (again, will be profitable only for large matrices), may use this code replacing `sapply` with `mc.lapply` or something like this.

Comment: And actually the sapply, could be coded into a multi core framework...

Comment: Agree; still OP wrote that this is not an option.

Comment: #Actually sapply is about 3 times slower than my baseline method
library(rbenchmark);
baseline <- function()
{;
 ncol <- 100;
 nrow <- 100;
 x <- matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow,ncol);
 y <- matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow,ncol);
 return(diag(cor(t(x),t(y))));
};
sapply.method <- function()
{;
 ncol <- 100;
 nrow <- 100;
 x <- matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow,ncol);
 y <- matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow,ncol);
 return(sapply(1:100,function(i) cor(x[i,],y[i,])));
};
benchmark(baseline=baseline(),sapply.method(),replications=10);

Comment: (your mileage may vary on by what factor it is slower)

Comment: For 100x100 matrix it is obvious; I believe that the problem requires a lot larger matrices and there my method will be faster. Still, I have written "your code is equivalent to:" instead of "use:" having that in mind -- this is how possible C/Fortran chunk should work.

Comment: Also, from no-multicore requirement one can conclude that this is indeed memory-bounded, so reducing memory complexity from $N^2$ to $N$ is also something worth playing.

Comment: The no-multicore was more a practical restriction, my colleague does not have a multicore machine, so parallelism wasn't going to help him.  I'm sure there is an entire other question to be asked regarding how to know a priori whether a parallel approach (with associated overhead) will be faster than a single threaded approach.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the relative numbers of "scores" and "subjects". The method you use calculates lots of cross-correlations which are not required. However, if there are relatively few "subjects" relative to "scores", then this probably doesn't matter too much, and the method you suggest is probably as good as anything, as it uses a small number of efficient blas operations. However, if there are a large number of "subjects" relative to scores, then it may well be quicker to loop over the rows computing the correlation for each pair separately, using the code suggested by "mbq".

Comment: Simulation supports your answer, and even with a transpose operation added to handle cases with more items than subjects, sapply beats diag(cor()), but only when there are notable asymmetries between the N of items and the N of subjects.

Answer (score 1):

It might be one of those cases where using a different [BLAS engine](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Can-I-use-a-fast-BLAS_003f) would help.  But I am not sure of it - it needs testing (and depends on your machine)